# MS Band HR sensor operating differently when in exercise mode?

Tags: android, microsoft-band

I have an Android app that receives and stores the current heart rate from the original Band at the 1 Hz frequency. I had some users take the Band with their smartphone and do some exercise to increase their HR for at least an hour. Here's the problem: When the Band is in it's normal state, the recorded HR values are significantly lower than actual (e.g. 80 instead of 120). However, when the Band is switched into the exercise mode via the tile, the HR values received by my app are pretty accurate.

This makes no sense to me. I know that without the SDK involvement switching into exercise mode causes the Band to start sampling HR every second instead of every 10 minutes, or whatever it is. But this is only relevant to the Microsoft Health Dashboard. As soon as I connect to the Band from an Android app, the sensor is turned on and goes into the 1 second sampling mode regardless of whether the user has also enabled exercise mode or not. The only difference on the Android side is the accuracy of the values.

I'm still not 100% convinced that this isn't user error (e.g. bad positioning of the sensor), but we've now had multiple people report the same thing, so I'm starting to suspect that switching into exercise mode also changes something about the way that the sensor operates beyond the sampling frequency. It's as though it becomes more sensitive, but why would MS use/create a sensor that has to be told when to expect high heart rate?

Does anyone have some ideas on what may be going on here?

Comment: HeartRate sample rate is always 1Hz, regardless of whether it's the exercise mode or when you're using the SDK.